# Having issues getting SVN server working

Tags: linux, svn

I'm trying to set up an SVN server on Linux (ubuntu, if it matters) and getting behavior that seems strange. When I'm on the actual server and try to just do `svn list file://...` it works and lists my test repo I have set up, but when trying to connect remotely from another server with `svn list svn://...` I get "No repositories found". All the google results I got told me it's usually an issue with the `svnserve` root path, but I've checked that three times now, and I know its right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're running *svnserve* if you're trying to access the SVN using `svn://`, so check if *svnserve* is running. I know this is silly, but sometimes it does happen; being able to connect to SVN using `file://` does not indicate if *svnserve* is running and configured properly.

To **configure *svnserve***, check [this tutorial](http://www.botsko.net/blog/2007/03/installing-subversion-on-centos/).

I would suggest you **configure SVN to be accessed by *http***: read [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-subversion-with-web-access-on-ubuntu/) how you can do that.

Comment: Shadow - you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using ssh+svn:// or https:// for accessing Subversion repositories, based on whether you want local users on your subversion server. In either case, my preference is for https://. You should find these more flexible than using svnserve.

Comment: I got the impression from my limited reading that http(s) was only for reading - i.e. you can't commit changes using it. Do you know of any setup information for your suggestions?

Comment: I strongly support what David said, I'd configure your repositories to be accessed via https - read my answer below

Answer (score 0):

- Is the `svnserve` run with correct permissions?
- Have you checked the logs from svnserve (usually `/var/log/` somehwere).
- Try running the client with a verbose or debug setting (`-v` and `-d` in most programs).
- Same, but for the server `svnserve` client.
- Are you testing from localhost? If so, check that connecting over loopback (interface name `lo`) actually is permitted.

While I run SVN through Apache2 (HTTP + SSL), I do recall having difficulty debugging what's going on, as the SVN error messages can be a tad too generic.